# Fixed points on complex function $T(z) = (1+i)z + 3-4i$

Tags: complex-numbers

If $T(z) = (1+i)z + 3-4i$ is a complex function, and I got this fixed point: $z=4+3i$

Is this correct? Are there more fixed points?

$(1+i)z+3-4i=z$

$3-4i=z-(1+i)z$

$3-4i=-iz$

$z=-\frac{3-4i}{i}=4+3i$

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Thank you, but... are there more fixed points?

Comment: No, that's all. Otherwise, I would not say that you were correct.

Comment: Connected: this [very recent question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4060604). Same homework ?

Comment: No, but the topic is similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is correct and there are no other fixed points. You can see this abstractly by saying that the fixed point equation is a degree one polynomial and therefore has at must one solution. More concretely, each deduction you made was "reversible" so each implication was actually an equivalence.

You had

$$
\begin{align*}
(1+i)z+3-4i=z &\implies 3-4i=z-(1+i)z\\
&\implies 3-4i=-iz\\
&\implies z=-\frac{3-4i}{i}=4+3i
\end{align*}
$$

but at each step the reverse implication holds as well. For instance, in the last step you divided by $-i$, so to go the other way you multiply by $-i$. Hence, you really have

$$
\begin{align*}
(1+i)z+3-4i=z &\Longleftrightarrow 3-4i=z-(1+i)z\\
&\Longleftrightarrow 3-4i=-iz\\
&\Longleftrightarrow z=-\frac{3-4i}{i}=4+3i.
\end{align*}
$$

In other words, $z$ is a fixed point of $T$ if and only if $z = 4+3i$. Be warned that not all manipulations you will do are reversible, however. $(-1)^2 = 1^2$ but you cannot reverse this to get $-1=1$!

Comment: It should be added that this transformation $T(z)=az+b$ is geometrically a similitude = a composition of a rotation **with respect to this fixed point** with angle arg(a)=$\pi/4$ followed by a homothety with ratio $|a]=\sqrt{2}$.